# Modelling a research experiment setup

Tags: c++

I'm creating an app in C++ designed to run an experiment. The model I created is here:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <filesystem>

namespace Experiment {
    enum Option { None = 0, Left = 1, Right = 2 };
    enum Mode { Stereo = 0, Mono_Left = 1, Mono_Right = 2 };

    struct Vector
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector& v);
    };

    struct Trial
    {
        std::string imageName = "";
        Option correctOption = Option::None;

        Vector position = {};
        Mode mode = Mode::Stereo;

        Option participantResponse = None;
        double duration = 0.0;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Trial& t);
    };

    struct Run
    {
        std::string id = "";
        std::string folderPath = "";

        float flickerRate = 0.1f;
        int timeOut = 8;

        int distance = 500;
        Vector dimensions = {1200, 1000};

        std::vector<Trial> trials = {};

        static Run CreateRun(const std::filesystem::path& configPath);
        void Export(const std::filesystem::path& path) const;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Run& r);
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector& v);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Trial& t);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Run& r);

    void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Vector& v);
    void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Trial& t);
    void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Run& r);

}
```

Each unique `Run` is created for every unique participant. The parameters are controlled via an external `json` configuration file. Each `Run` contains a vector of `Trials`, which is a single question with its own parameters.

I also have a basic Vector class to model the `position` parameter of the Trial, as well as enums for both `Option` and `Mode`.

I'm fairly new to C++, so I was mainly wondering if my `operator<<` and `from_json` functions are standard, as well as my use of the `friend` tag. Any other suggestions are also very welcome.

Comment: This is just a header file, which makes this question about stub code, rather than a concrete working implementation. Please include your implementation, as well as a sample JSON configuration for clarity.